# How to display a concatenate string into combobox and it popup in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

My Combobox :

XAML :

```
<ComboBox Name="CB_SALARIE" IsEditable="True" Height="35"      VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5,50,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding }"     SelectionChanged="CB_SALARIE_SelectionChanged">
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock DataContext="{Binding }">
             <TextBlock.Text>
                 <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1}">
                     <Binding Path="NAME"/>
                     <Binding Path="FIRSTNAME"/>
                 </MultiBinding>
             </TextBlock.Text>
         </TextBlock>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
   <ComboBox.Style>
       <Style>
          <EventSetter Event="TextBox.TextChanged" Handler="TextBox_TextChanged" />
       </Style>
   </ComboBox.Style>
</ComboBox>
```

C# :

```
private ObservableCollection<t_salarie> obsSalarie = new ObservableCollection<t_salarie>();

c_salarie c_sal = new c_salarie();
foreach (t_salarie item in c_sal.GetListAllSalarie())
    obsSalarie.Add(item);
this.CB_SALARIE.ItemsSource = obsSalarie;
```

But with this method, in popup it's display the NAME et the FIRSTNAME but in the combobox's textblock is display ApplicationName.ObjectName

Textchanged event and SelectionChanged event isn't implementated yet.

Need your help to solve this problem.

Comment: Can you add your class code ?

Comment: Binding issue, post your code

Comment: ItemsSource="{Binding }"    <- Are you sure this is the correct binding for the ComboBox? I think it should be {Binding obsSalarie}

Comment: Thank you for help me, i have found a solution : public override string ToString() into my class code